# How to convert amount in crores to decimal value in php?

Tags: php, number-formatting

I have a price of the product which is Rs 5005000/- (50 lakh and 5 thousand rupees). I want to convert to like 50.5 lakhs. Is there any PHP functions to do that. I tried searching StackOverflow and keep getting number_words conversion only. In a site called 99 acres they have done it like this: http://www.99acres.com/Bangalore-Real-Estate.htm. Can anyone help

Comment: I think it should be `50.05` and not `50.5`

Comment: ya. i hope you all got the logic.

Comment: Rs 5005000/- will be shown as 50.05 lakh not 50.5lakh

Comment: Are you concerning only about lakhs , how it should be in the case of Crores or thousands

Comment: yes yes. 5050000 as 50.5 lacs and 5005000 as 50.05 lacs.

Comment: So in case if you have lakhs(10 Lakhs) it should be converted like 5050000 as 50.5 lacs and don't do anything in case of  50500000(5 crores) right.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
    <?php
function count_digit($number) {
  return strlen($number);
}

function divider($number_of_digits) {
    $tens="1";

  if($number_of_digits>8)
    return 10000000;

  while(($number_of_digits-1)>0)
  {
    $tens.="0";
    $number_of_digits--;
  }
  return $tens;
}
//function call
$num = "789";
$ext="";//thousand,lac, crore
$number_of_digits = count_digit($num); //this is call :)
    if($number_of_digits>3)
{
    if($number_of_digits%2!=0)
        $divider=divider($number_of_digits-1);
    else
        $divider=divider($number_of_digits);
}
else
    $divider=1;

$fraction=$num/$divider;
$fraction=number_format($fraction,2);
if($number_of_digits==4 ||$number_of_digits==5)
    $ext="k";
if($number_of_digits==6 ||$number_of_digits==7)
    $ext="Lac";
if($number_of_digits==8 ||$number_of_digits==9)
    $ext="Cr";
echo $fraction." ".$ext;
?>
```

1. count the number_of_digit
2. Take (number_of_digit-1) digit tens value
3. divide it.
4. find the extension of value from number of digits.
5. output will be

> 123456789  = 12.34 Cr
>
> 23456789  = 2.34 Cr
>
> 3456789  = 34.56 Lac
>
> 456789  = 4.56 Lac
>
> 56789  = 56.78 K
>
> 6789  = 6.78 K

If any testcase fails . Please let me know. I will rectify

Comment: for a amount 24500000 which is 2 crores and 45 lacs, the result is 24.50.

Comment: i edited my code please check again... you can see updated code output below

Comment: yes its the right answer. even there is small correctness needed like if the amount is 24505000 which should give 2.4505 cr but even that is neglected.

Comment: how can i use this on a repeat region using mysqli php. 
I placed within a repeat region then i got error as cant use previously declared functions or so. SO i used: 
`if (!function_exists('count_digit')) {
-- your codes --
}`

Now only first record's result is shown.

FYI i have placed this inside repeat region.

Comment: @RohanKhude please help. please look at above comment.

Comment: @MohammedKumel, dont use functions in loop. Keep it outside of loop.

Comment: @RohanKhude not possible cause i got multiple values to be converted.

Comment: @RohanKhude i moved first section out of loop. it seem to work.. thanks

Answer (score 3):

You Can also try my code, May be it will help you:

```
      function no_to_words($no)
{
    if($no == 0) {
        return ' ';

    }else {
        $n =  strlen($no); // 7
        switch ($n) {
            case 3:
                $val = $no/100;
                $val = round($val, 2);
                $finalval =  $val ." hundred";
                break;
            case 4:
                $val = $no/1000;
                $val = round($val, 2);
                $finalval =  $val ." thousand";
                break;
            case 5:
                $val = $no/1000;
                $val = round($val, 2);
                $finalval =  $val ." thousand";
                break;
            case 6:
                $val = $no/100000;
                $val = round($val, 2);
                $finalval =  $val ." lakh";
                break;
            case 7:
                $val = $no/100000;
                $val = round($val, 2);
                $finalval =  $val ." lakh";
                break;
            case 8:
                $val = $no/10000000;
                $val = round($val, 2);
                $finalval =  $val ." crore";
                break;
            case 9:
                $val = $no/10000000;
                $val = round($val, 2);
                $finalval =  $val ." crore";
                break;

            default:
                echo "";
        }
        return $finalval;

    }
}

echo no_to_words(12345676);
```

You can modify function based on your requirement.

Comment: input - 123456789

output - 12.3456789 crore

and so on

Answer (score 2):

Just find the length of the input number, divide it according to its length (crores or lakhs), round the number to 2 digits and then add the extension with the number.

```
function convertCurrency($number)
{
    // Convert Price to Crores or Lakhs or Thousands
    $length = strlen($number);
    $currency = '';

    if($length == 4 || $length == 5)
    {
        // Thousand
        $number = $number / 1000;
        $number = round($number,2);
        $ext = "Thousand";
        $currency = $number." ".$ext;
    }
    elseif($length == 6 || $length == 7)
    {
        // Lakhs
        $number = $number / 100000;
        $number = round($number,2);
        $ext = "Lac";
        $currency = $number." ".$ext;

    }
    elseif($length == 8 || $length == 9)
    {
        // Crores
        $number = $number / 10000000;
        $number = round($number,2);
        $ext = "Cr";
        $currency = $number.' '.$ext;
    }

    return $currency;
}

// Call the function with a number input 
convertCurrency(100000);
```

Just Clean and Simple. :)
(If any testcase fails, just let me know. I will fix it)

Answer (score 1):

```
function convert_rupee($amount){
    $length = strlen($amount);
    if($length>=6 && $length <=7){
        echo round($amount/100000,2).' Lac(s)';
    }else if($length>=8 && $length <=9){
        echo round($amount/10000000,2).' Cr.';
    }else if($length>=4 && $length <=5){
        echo round($amount/1000,2).' K';

    }else{ echo 0;}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try it this may help you ,

```
 function cnvCrtoDec($number) {
     $unitArray =   array("4"=>"K","5"=>"K","6"=>"L","7"=>"L","8"=>"Cr","9"=>"Cr");
     $numLen        = strlen($number);
     if ($numLen > 3 ) {
        foreach ($unitArray as $nmLen=>$unit) {
            if ($numLen == $nmLen) {
               if ($nmLen % 2 == 0) {
                  $remNumber    = substr($number,1,3);
                  $ckNmGtZer    = ($remNumber[0]+$remNumber[1]+$remNumber[2]);
                  if ($ckNmGtZer < 1) { 
                      $remNumber    = "";
                  } else {
                     if ( ($remNumber[1]    == 0) && ($remNumber[2] == 0)   ) {
                        $remNumber[1]   = "";
                        $remNumber[2]   = "";   
                  } 
             }
             echo $number   = substr($number,0,$numLen-$nmLen+1) . "." .  $remNumber . "$unit";             
    } else {
         $remNumber     = substr($number,2,3);
         $ckNmGtZer = ($remNumber[0]+$remNumber[1]+$remNumber[2]);
         if ($ckNmGtZer < 1) { 
            $remNumber  = 0;
        } else {
            if (($remNumber[1]  == 0) && ($remNumber[2] == 0)) {
                $remNumber[1]   = "";
                $remNumber[2]   = "";   
            }   
        }
        echo $number    = substr($number,0,$numLen-$nmLen+2) . ".". $remNumber . "$unit";   
       }
     }
 }
 } else {
    echo $number . "Rs";    
 }
 }

 cnvCrtoDec($number     = "155005");
```

Answer (score 0):

Following is the Swift method, you may find useful once you convert it in PHP
and may be someone other find it use full find for same answer and also if you just want format number with no currency symbol following code might be usefull

**SWIFT 4**

```
static func convertToCurrency(value: Double) -> String {
    var shortAmt = value
    var suf = ""

    if (value >= 10000000.0) {
        suf = " C"
        shortAmt /= 10000000.0
    } else if (value >= 1000000.0) {
        suf = " M";
        shortAmt /= 1000000.0;
    } else if (value >= 100000.0) {
        suf = " L"
        shortAmt /= 100000.0
    } else if (value >= 1000.0) {
        suf = " K"
        shortAmt /= 1000.0
    }

    let numberFormatter = NumberFormatter()
    numberFormatter.numberStyle = .currency
    numberFormatter.maximumFractionDigits = 2
    numberFormatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en-IN") // Define your currency symbol type
    //numberFormatter.currencySymbol = ""   //Add this line if you don't want to add currency symbol
    let amtAsStr = numberFormatter.string(from: shortAmt as NSNumber)

    return "\(amtAsStr ?? "")\(suf)"
}
```